# Regression with unrestricted betas

Tags: r, regression, restrictions

Say for, instance, if I were to regress a unrestricted model such as:

$$Y_it=\beta_0+V_{it}(\gamma_0+\gamma_1X_{it})+D\chi_{it}+\epsilon_{it}$$

In which I would be mainly interested in obtaining the $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ coefficients. Is there a good package for this type of estimation in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear regression with interaction term

$$
\beta_0+V_{it}(\gamma_0+\gamma_1X_{it})+D\chi_{it} =
\beta_0+\gamma_0 V_{it} +  \gamma_1X_{it} V_{it} +D\chi_{it}
$$

Comment: Yes, I see it was a stupid question. Thank you o/

Comment: @JohnDoe Sometimes simple solutions hide in plain sight.